# SQL saving to a Temporary table is not working

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

i have the following sql query

```
    SELECT P.catalogid, 
       Sum(numitems)     numitems, 
       Sum(ignoreditems) ignoreditems, 
       P.supplierid, 
       P.cname, 
       P.cprice, 
       P.cstock, 
       P.ccode, 
       P.minstock, 
       P.pother4, 
       P.processedsucssessfully, 
       P.notprocessed, 
       Y.backorder 
INTO   ##tempt 
FROM   ##temporderstable P 
       JOIN supporder Y 
         ON P.catalogid = Y.catalogid 
GROUP  BY P.catalogid, 
          P.supplierid, 
          P.cname, 
          P.cprice, 
          P.cstock, 
          P.ccode, 
          P.minstock, 
          P.pother4, 
          Y.backorder, 
          P.processedsucssessfully, 
          P.notprocessed
```

i am trying to save the result of join into another temporty table, but when i try to access the new table from another query it says invalid object name, is this the right way to save the result of this query to `##tempt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit temp table declaration and then check!!

Like this

```
CREATE TABLE ##tempt (
supplierid int,
other fields ..)
```

Comment: Ideally it should did you temporary table ##temporderstable P  exist, means does it give any compile error when you execute statement.